# как зарандомить числа, которые будут находиться в одной из четвертей декартовой системы?

Tags: c++, случайные-числа

подскажите пожалуйста, как зарандомить вещественные числа с помощью функции rand(), находящиеся в первой и третьей четверти декартовой системы? диапазон (-100;100)
у меня контейнер типа pair, обе координаты - те самые числа

единственное, что могу сделать(

```
c=-100+rand()%200+(-100+rand()%200)*100.0
```

Comment: @nightflash, знаю, поэтому заполняю контейнер с типом pair

Comment: Поясните, что вам нужно? Случайные действительные числа от -100 до +100? А при чем тогда первый и третий квадранты?

Comment: @Harry, пояснил в самом задании, извините

Comment: @Руслан отредактировал свой ответ. Теперь точно должно работать

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как-то так наверное:

```
int myrandom(int k)
{
  return rand() % k;
}

x = (-10000 + myrandom(20000)) / 100;
y = myrandom(10000) / 100;
if (x < 0) y = -y;
```

Comment: И что означает `rand()` с аргументом? Где вы его взяли? (и кто, интересно, кроме зачем-то принявшего его ТС еще плюсует ответ?)

Comment: @avp забавно) Перепутал языки.

Comment: @avp дополнил ответ. Думаю так будет честнее.

Comment: Не слишком хорошая идея, заменять стандартные функции (см. [man random](https://linux.die.net/man/3/random)) своими